# Convert an existing commercial web page with a table of tiles into a friendlier table or list?

Tags: javascript, tile

People,

YouTube's "My List":

https://www.netflix.com/browse/my-list

is crap and doesn't work properly and this layout of my Android Apps is just annoying and inefficient:

https://play.google.com/apps?hl=en&gl=US

Before I start re-inventing wheels (I am very much a JS novice) - is there something in existence that will allow me to convert these pages into my own pages with the information in a (sortable) table or list? - ie with ONE item per row and NO images or at least much smaller thumbnails for each item?

Thanks,
Phil.

Comment: If you want to provide examples of layout, it is better to use a screenshot rather than a link. Especially if the links indicated require a login. Having said that, you can change the layout of a visited website by modifying the HTML and CSS code with the browser DevTool (although the alteration would not be permanent) but I doubt there is some sort of automatic tool to do what you want because the "same" layout can be produced in different ways. [...]

Comment: [...] There are browser settings and plugins that allow you to remove images, increase font size and do other less extensive and "radical" modifications, though.